# Option to merge webapps icons into one Launcher icon

Tags: webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to group apps in Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227146/how-to-group-apps-in-unity-launcher)

I activated the webapps PPA that enables me to have web pages integrated into Ubuntu but since I use several today I noticed my launcher had A LOT of icons now. For example I have facebook, launchpad, grooveshark, gmailm linkedin an others. Is there a way to gather them all in one icon that I can right click or left click and see each one in a menu?

Comment: I hate this effect of the webapps... really hope they add the feature you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not particular only to webapps but to any icon in the Launcher.

You can just group all of them using [`drawers`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/drawers) [image: Install drawers]

[image]

Please refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227146/how-to-group-apps-in-unity-launcher) for more details.

Comment: Very good answer (And question). Will mark this question as duplicate of yours. Yours in cleaner and better.

Answer (score 1):

You can [add a feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/webapps/+bugs) to the Webapps Launchpad project.