# How to group apps in Unity Launcher

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I put more applications in a Unity icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81732/can-i-put-more-applications-in-a-unity-icon)

Gnome Panels used to have trays, where I can add multiple entries so that I can group applications together.

How can I achieve such an effect in Unity?